# Trying launch program written in 3.8.5 python version through 3.9.2 version. How solve this?

Tags: python, terminal, version

I have 2 versions of Python on my system - 3.8.5 and 3.9.2. Recently I've tried to launch my program written in 3.8.5 version through 3.9.2 version in my Terminal which gave me this result:

```
(base) Kate@Kates-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/Kate/game.py 
/Users/Kate/game.py: line 1: answer: command not found
/Users/Kate/game.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/Kate/game.py: line 3: `    num = int(input())'
(base) Kate@Kates-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Please tell me if that is a bug in the program or because of different versions of Python?

Also when I tried to debug my program it gave me a different type of bug as you

[image: can see here]

Comment: both version should work the same.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `answer : 77` is not correct code in python - remove it or use `answer = 77` if you want to assign value to variable

Comment: you have `if` without code after `:` but it is also incorrect in Python - you need at least command `pass`

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
answer = 77
```

instead of

```
answer : 77
```

That is all.

And `answer : 77` should gives error on all versions - also with 3.8.5 and 3.9.2.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I've already solve this problem using another method but thank you!

Comment: And you are right. I didn't read documentation :(. Forgive me for that.  I will mend it.